# Duda sobre valor 'nul', no 'NULL'

Tags: javascript, json

Un poco de contexto: Estoy en el desarrollo de una aplicacion que reproduce contenido. Cuando un contenido es mostrado se guarda dentro de un archivo local la cantidad de impresiones que se han realizado y despues se guardan en una base de datos (Esto se hizo de esta manera para controlar el caso en que no haya una conexion estable a internet).

Hace un tiempo nos dimos cuenta que suele guardarnos (A veces, no siempre) un valor 'nul' (Si, nul, con una sola 'l') dentro del archivo JSON y a pesar de que tratamos de buscar de que se trata no sabemos a que se refiere ese mismo valor.

Se trata de un caso 'especial' de NULL?

Comment: Creo que es un back slash
Mira esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54272131/javascript-json-strings-with-nul-0

Comment: Además del enlace que mencionaron en el comentario, puede que sea relevante que menciones en la pregunta el motor de base de datos que estás utilizando.